# What is the difference between HttpServer::listen() and HttpServer::bind() in actix-web?

Tags: rust, httpserver, actix-web

I'm currently working on an actix-web application but I have some difficulty in understanding how  [`HttpServer.listen()`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/struct.HttpServer.html#method.listen) and [`HttpServer.bind()`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/struct.HttpServer.html#method.bind) are different and what do these functions do.

Comment: _"I know that the later function takes a `TcpListener` as an argument."_ That is _the_ difference between them. You have answered your own question, it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpServer::bind` takes a (bunch of) socket address(es), resolves them, opens the corresponding connections, then listens.

`HttpServer::listen` just listens.

rustdoc has a `source` link next to most functions, so you can actually [browse the code to `bind`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/src/actix_web/server.rs.html#341-349) and it's pretty straightforward:

```rust
    pub fn bind<A: net::ToSocketAddrs>(mut self, addrs: A) -> io::Result<Self> {
        let sockets = self.bind2(addrs)?;

        for lst in sockets {
            self = self.listen(lst)?;
        }

        Ok(self)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one practical distinction, made in the book Zero to Production in Rust, on page 40. It changes the call from `bind` to `listen` when you want to bind to port 0, which is the linux way of saying that you want to bind on a random port. Using `listen`, the application can tell you which port it actually received.

Comment: "when you want to bind to port 0, which is the linux way of saying that you want to bind on a random port" it's the unix way not the linux way. Specifically it's the [Berkeley Sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) way, which is why pretty much all platforms (including windows) follow it. Also technically it's not "a random port", it's an unused port in [the ephemeral port range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port), different OS may select the ports differently.